# Tortoise| SVN command line error : non existent in revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Continuously getting error : non-existent in revision 559.
However for some other repositories they are working fine.
Exactly what does this error mean?
Appreciate any solution for this...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requested object does not exist in *this* revision, may be moved|deleted earlier

Comment: +1 & Thanks Lazy. This is indeed the case here. I cross checked by verifying other repositories where this error wasn't shown up & the files Do exist there while in former case NO file exists.